# Kibana error on startup (incompatible nodes)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I started using elastic search 7.3.2 and kibana 6.8.3 on mac os mojave 10.14.5.

When kibana starts I got following errors:
log   [15:21:03.052] [error][status][plugin:xpack_main@7.3.2] Status changed from yellow to red - This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v7.3.2 on all nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: **v6.2.4** @ 127.0.0.1:9200 (127.0.0.1)
  log   [15:21:03.052] [error][status][plugin:graph@7.3.2] Status changed from yellow to red - This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v7.3.2 on all nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: **v6.2.4** @ 127.0.0.1:9200 (127.0.0.1)

in the past (several years ago) I used version 6.2.4. How can I get those nodes removed ? I do not need them anymore, how can I remove them in order to let kibana starts correctly ?

Thanks for any help if any

Comment: please share more information. like how many elasticsearch nodes do you have?

Comment: I have only one node.

Answer (score 5):

use kibana 6.2.4. or upgrade the elasticsearch to 7.3.2. the elasticsearch and kibana should be the same version.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help, I solved by deleting the data folder linked from elasticsearch.yml configuration file.

Answer (score -3):

Check your Elasticsearch cluster settings `elasticsearch.yml`, for each host in your cluster:

`cluster.name:`

`node.name:`

`discovery.seed_hosts:`

`cluster.initial_master_nodes:`

If your old host is still part of your cluster or discovery, it will continue to throw these errors.

Comment: the problem obviously is about the incompatibility between kibana version and elasticsearch version.  what are you talking about?